# How to change default font size on iOS Mail for outgoing emails?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I know that you can change the default font through the Format pane:

[image]

But if you change the font size, you only changing it for the very email you’re composing.

Is there a way to change the **default** font size?

My software version is 13.3.1.

Comment: Not possible with Mail as far as  I know.  Try another email app, maybe Outlook.  (Same situation for MacOS by the way), or look for an add-on in the App Store.